# Trace orthonormality in irreducible reps. of semisimple Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebra, trace

I have a question about an excerpt from Peskin & Schröder "Introduction to QFT" (see below). I understand the claim that I have marked as:

> "Let $\{t^a\}$ be a basis of a Lie algebra such that there is an irreducible representation $d$ such that tr$[d(t^a) d(t^b)] = C(d) \delta^{ab}$ for some non-zero constant $C(d)$. Then for every other irrep. $d'$, there is a constant $C(d')$ such that tr$[d(t^a) d(t^b)] = C(d) \delta^{ab}$."

My first question is whether this interpretation is correct. My second is: If it is correct, then what is a nice argument to see that it is true? (A reference to some textbook containing a proof would also be very welcome).

[image: Excerpt from Peskin Schröder]

Comment: All of the group theory books you [should have perused](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/comprehensive-book-on-group-theory-for-physicists) have a basic discussion of orthonormalizing your Lie algebra basis, and recursive computation of representation indices.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345333/index-of-representation-of-sun-fundamental-and-adjoint).

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and text to display math and text.  Using images of eitehr is very strongly discouraged on this site.

Comment: You could ask a sophisticated question about the correlations of indices among representations, but, hey, what are the 40 texts referred to and MSE for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question in chapter 14.9 of "Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations" by Jürgen Fuchs an Christoph Schweigert. If anyone else ever stumbles over this SE page: The precise statement would be

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra and let $\{t^a\}$ be a basis of it such that there is a representation $d$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that tr$[d(t^a) d(t^b)] = C(d) \delta^{ab}$ for some non-zero constant $C(d)$. Then for every other representation $d'$, there is a (possibily zero) constant $C(d')$ such that tr$[d(t^a) d(t^b)] = C(d') \delta^{ab}$.

The proof is a beautifully simple argument: Given an arbitrary rep. $d$, we can define an ad invariant inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ via tr$[d(t^a) d(t^b)]$. But for simple Lie algebras, the Killing form is the unique ad invariant inner product up to a constant prefactor. Thus all of these inner product are proportional to each other.